# How do I provide a valid OAuth/NLAuth authorization header for NetSuite?

Tags: php, oauth, postman

Being new to NetSuite and Post Man, I wanted to get my very first RESTlet up and working using Token Based Authentication which I have already set up, therefore I have:

- Account ID
- Application ID
- Consumer Key
- Consumer Secret
- Token ID
- Token Secret

This particular role designated already has Web Services only checkbox ticked as it was indicated in a few guides I followed. I also added permissions appropriate to their intended task.

I am currently experimenting tests through my Post Man REST Client by inserting my RESTlet's external URL into the address bar, included the following header keys and their values: (Using the format > Key: Value)

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: OAuth realm="###",oauth_consumer_key="###",oauth_token="###",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="?????",oauth_nonce="?????",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="?????"
```

I already replaced the hashes ### with my NetSuite provided information, however anything marked with question marks ??? are generated using php code . (Sensitive information were intentionally removed and left blank on here)

As a result, I received a 403 Forbidden error ("InvalidSignature" on our saved search Login Audit)

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT",
        "message": "Invalid login attempt."
    }
}
```

As an alternative, I have used NLAuth approach instead to no success:

```
NLAuth nlauth_account=#####, nlauth_email=###@###.###, nlauth_signature=######
```

Where the hashes contain my account ID, related email address and the password respectively. I have also tried nlauth_otp containing my usual 6-digit pass code from my authentication application.

Regardless, I received a 401 Unauthorized error (< Blank > on our saved search Login Audit)

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "TWO_FA_REQD",
        "message": "Two-Factor Authentication required"
    }
}
```

Since this is my first RESTlet, I was attempting to display product inventory from NetSuite to products stored on Magento.

In terms of researching done within Magento DevDocs, I have followed [DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html) and created an instance of an Integration API with the intent of being able to link more content to and from NetSuite and Magento in the future.

As a form of troubleshooting, I did try the Post Man's Authorization tab for OAuth 1.0 but I received a 400 Bad Request error after entering my TBA credentials in.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "INVALID_REQUEST",
        "message": "The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax."
    }
}
```

I admit I am leaving something out unintentionally or have forgotten a step somewhere before here. Any help would much be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look it:
OAuth 1.0a Wrapper for Use with NetSuite's Suitescript 2.0
https://github.com/mark-keaton/oauth-netsuite